# Simplifying a nonhomogenous ODE via limits as t --> infinity.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am self studying a systems biology paper on segmentation in evolutionary developmental biology and trying to replicate the simulation. The simulation implements systems of differential equations which model the transcriptional network in play for a given cell. The following network and its correspond system of ODEs is where I am struggling a little bit:

Network 1:

[image: Network 1]

System of ODES:
$$ \dfrac{dP}{dt} = \dfrac{G^{n_1}}{G^{n_1} + G_P^{n_1}} \dfrac{1}{1 + \left(\dfrac{R(t)}{R_P}\right)^{n_2}}\cdot S_P - \delta_P P \hspace{10mm} (1)$$

$$ \dfrac{dR}{dt} = \dfrac{G^{n_3}}{G^{n_3} + G_R^{n_3}} \cdot S_R - \delta_R R \hspace{36mm} (2)$$

where $G$ is a morphogen gradient dependent only on position, $x$, $$ G = \exp (-0.05x)$$

and can be treated a constant along with the variables $$\delta_R, \delta_P, G_P, G_R, R_P, S_P, n_1, n_2, n_3.$$

Solving equation (2) using an integrating factor results in:
$$R(t) = \dfrac{G^{n_3}}{G^{n_3} + G_R^{n_3}} \cdot \dfrac{S_R}{\delta_R} \cdot (1 - e^{\delta_R t}) \hspace{26mm} (3)$$

My issue comes with trying to solve equation (1) due to the $R(t)$ term. If I'm not mistaken, that term renders equation (1) into a non-homogenous, linear differential equation. Is that correct?

If so, I solved (1) as a homogenous equation, then tried using the method of undetermined coefficients to construct a particular solution. However, the result was too complex for me to solve. It looks something like this:
    $$ \left(-\dfrac{A}{\delta _R} e^{-\delta _R t}\right) = \dfrac{G(x)^{n_1}}{G(x)^{n_1} + G^{n_1}_P}  \dfrac{1}{1+\left(\dfrac{R(t)}{R_P}\right)^{n_2} } S_P - \delta _P \left(A e^{-\delta _R t} \right)$$

I then thought I might be able to take the limit as $t \rightarrow \infty$ to simply $R(t)$, then plug that value into (1) as a constant, then solve (1) as a normal linear ODE by using a integrating factor. But as I write this out I begin to think that that approach is deathly incorrect.

After two years away from mathematics, my mind is a bit frazzled at this point as to which direction to proceed in from here - or, it is very likely I have made an elementary mistake in either my approach or calculations.

If anyone has any suggestions or pointers in the right direction, I would be immensely appreciative!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loosely speaking, after you've solved equation (2) for $R(t)$ and substituted the solution to equation (1), you obtained a first order linear inhomogeneous equation à la

$$ \frac{dP}{dt} = \mathcal{F}(t) - \delta_p P .$$

The general solution to this equation could be written as

$$ P_{\text{general}}(t) = \left (\text{const} + \int_{0}^{t} \mathcal{F}(u)\cdot \exp(\delta_p u)\; du \right ) \cdot \exp(-\delta_p t)$$

This was done by Lagrange method (it is also called variation of constants: in short, you are trying to find particular solution of form $C(t) \exp(-\delta_p t)$, plug it back into equation and you obtain formula for $C(t)$ in integral form). I think that was the solution that you wanted to obtain when you were speaking about method of undetermined coefficients.

Well, all crazy formulas are now hidden inside integral, but at least you see what kind of solution you should get at the end.